# Search Results Templates Strange Cacheing Behaviour

Tags: theming, search, caching

I've been trying to resolve an issue with my search results templates.

There are two scenarios that I could really use some help with understanding:

1. I have no search result templates inside my theme, just using the default system ones. I'm manipulating their variables to control output in template.php using hook_preprocess_search_result(). This is fine and displays exactly how I want it, until a few hours go by and all of a sudden it seems as through the preprocess function is ignored and the results revert back to their default appearance.

I can fix this by clearing the cache, and sometimes it takes a couple of clears.

2. I have search results templates within my theme. This time a similar thing happens which seems to involve the cache but rather than reverting to the default appearance after a few hours, the results disappear altogether. Strangely, the pagination links are still displayed normally, and I can move through the pages of results, but no results are output.

Ideally I'd like to use the 1st approach i.e. just using the preprocess function.

I have the search restrict module installed but I've ruled that out by disabling it.

I've also tried the cache exclude module and configured it to just exclude search results pages but again to no avail.

Could anybody shed any light on this problem? Am I missing something obvious?